# Microservice State Synchronization

Tags: microservices, state, docker-swarm

We are working on an application that has a WebSocket connection to every client. For high availability and load balancing purposes, we would like to scale the receiving micro service. As the WebSocket connection is used to propagate the state of a client to every other client it is important to synchronize the current state of a client with all other instances of the receiving micro service. It is also important that the state has to be reset when a client disconnects.

To give you some specs:

- We are using docker swarm
- Its a NodeJS Backend and an Angular 9 Frontend

We have looked into multiple ideas, for example:

- Redis Cache (The state would not be deleted if the instance fails.)
- Queues/Topics (This would mean every instance has to keep track of the current state of all clients.)
- WebSockets between instances (This looks promising but is not really scalable.)

What is the best practice to sync the state of a micro service between multiple instances while making sure that there are no inconsistencies? How are you solving this issue? Are we missing something obvious? Any tips and tricks?

We appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be 100% what you want to hear, but generally people advise that [all microservices should be stateless](https://12factor.net/processes).

An overall application, of course, has state, and databases, persistent event streams or key-value caches (e.g. Redis) are excellent ways of persisting this. Ideally this is bounded per service though, otherwise you risk end up [writing a distributed monolith](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/distributed-monolith-vs-microservices/).

Hard to say in your particular case, but perhaps rethink how state is stored conceptually, and make that more explicit - determining what is cache (for performance) and what is genuine state that should be persisted externally (e.g. to Redis & a database), that allows many service instances to use instantly, thus making sure they can are truly [disposable processes](https://12factor.net/disposability).